# How compatible wso2 DSS for application development?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

How compatible WSO2 DSS for application development?

It means, we need to write all of our transaction (insert, update, delete, select) in the DSS.

There are any pros / cons?

I'm not sure, but some of big query takes long time over the web service.

Any suggestion or case study for application development.

BR,
Eba

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 Dss is very flexible and have enough features for you to use it for app development. You can expose all your data services ops(select,update,delete,insert and any  complex data base stored procedures) thru wso2 DS, and invoke them in a light weight manner from your apps.  i.e You can you can expose each such operation as SOAP/REST. In your case, exposing them via REST is the way to go. If you want you can expose a set of ops as a group and etc. There are quite a few such useful features in DSS you can find as a app developer.

THis is the wiki doc for WSO2 DSS https://docs.wso2.org/display/dss311/WSO2+Data+Services+Server+Documentation.

Here is how to expose data services as REST resources
https://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS311/Exposing+Data+as+REST+Resources